# how to get invoice id or details from order?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, invoice

how to get invoice deatils or id by order object ?

```
$orderObject = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
```

Any Method to get `invoice_id` from above order object ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got solution to get invoice data from order

```
 $orderObject = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);

$invoiceIds = $orderObject->getInvoiceCollection()->getAllIds();
```

Answer (score 5):

Your code only provides the one invoice which has been ***created first for  this order***. But ***an order may have multiple invoices*** as Magento is capable of creating multiple partial invoices, then you will have multiple invoice details.

The following code loads all associated invoices:

```
 $orderObject = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);

 $invoiceCollection = $orderObject->getInvoiceCollection();
 foreach($invoiceCollection as $invoice):
    //var_dump($invoice);
    $invoiceId =  $invoice->getId();
    $invoiceIncrementId =  $invoice->getIncrementId();
 endforeach;
```

Comment: Yes you are right,I changed my code